# Highcharts (highstock.js) exporting function does not work on Embedded Visualforce pages

Tags: jquery, salesforce, highcharts, visualforce

I'm using Stockcharts (provided by Highcharts) to create differant charts to display data using embedded visualforce pages. Im trying to export and download charts as .png etc.

My code works fine and it starts downloading but giving the following error, and stops.

> The page at 'https' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content
>   from 'http'.  This content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

But I can download the chart without any problem, when I load the chart in salesforce giving the Id. 
Ex: "emea.salesforce.com/apex/barchart?id=a052000000GfNw2" in https

So I assume the error occurs only in embedded visualforce pages.
Is there any way I can get rid of this problem and download charts in embedded visualforce pages?

Comment: I wonder this happens due to the iframe used in the charts ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try adding the 's' to your 'http' to get rid of that error.  Although it still may not work.  SFDC is really locking down cross-domain requests.